# Append fields from a document to other document having matching field MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to write MongoDB query to accomplish something which is explained below. I don't know whether it is possible in mongoDB or not. I know how to insert a field in single document or multiple document but my problem is little advance to that. 
I have a collection (say for "procs") having 5000 documents like:

{
    "sid": 1
    "procs": [
        {
            "post_time": 0,
            "p_start": 1487303363.8170002,
            "pid": 1
        }
    ]
}

Here is the another document-2 from different collection(say for "acqs"):

{
    "sn": 10302301,
    "date": "2017-12-11",
    "sid": 1
    "acqs": [{
            "aqid": 2,
            "aq_end": 1487305607.342
        }
    ]
}
This collection also contains around 5000 documents.

Now i want to insert "sn" and "date" fields from document 2 to document 1 corresponding to same "sid" field values.
so i want output something like this:
 {
    "sn": 10302301,
    "date": "2017-12-11",
    "sid": 1
    "procs": [{
            "post_time": 0,
            "p_start": 1487303363.8170002,
            "pid": 1
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mongoDb , you can use $lookup

```
db.procs.aggregrate([
   {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "acqs",
          localField: "sid",
          foreignField: "sid",
          as: "procs_docs"
        }
   }

])
```

Result Will be like :

```
  { 
"sn": 10302301, "date": "2017-12-11", "sid": 1 ,
"acqs": [{ "aqid": 2, "aq_end": 1487305607.342 } ]
"procs_doc": ["sid": 1,procs:{ "post_time": 0, "p_start": 1487303363.8170002, "pid": 1 } ] }
```

If you are using mongoose then you can use populate method of mongoose ,which lets you reference documents in other collections.